# JOIN with GROUP BY causing SUM() logic issues

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Query -

```
sel TableName, DatabaseName, sum(CurrentPerm/(1024*1024*1024)) as Size_in_GB
        from dbc.tablesize
        group by 1,2
        order by GB desc
```

result -

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
| TableName | DBName | Size_in_GB |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| WRP       | A      |  28,350.01 |
| CPC       | B      |  19,999.37 |
| SDF       | C      |  13,263.67 |
| DB1400    | D      |  13,200.26 |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

From above simple query I can see that table **WRP** of **database A** is near **28350 GB**

Now I am trying to join another table `dbc.indices` to use the column `IndexType` for filtering but now the Size_in_GB changes for all tables.

```
sel a.TableName,a.DatabaseName, sum(CurrentPerm/(1024*1024*1024)) as Size_in_GB from dbc.tablesize a
join dbc.indices b on a.TableName = b.TableName and a.DatabaseName=b.DatabaseName
--where b.indexType='P'
group by 1,2
order by Size_in_GB desc
```

Result is this -

```
+-----------+--------+------------+
| TableName | DBName | Size_in_GB |
+-----------+--------+------------+
| WRP       | A      |  56,700.02 |
| CPC       | B      |  39,998.74 |
| DB1400    | D      |  39,600.78 |
+-----------+--------+------------+
```

Now the same table is twice the size i.e. **WRP** is **56700 GB**. (Similar for other tables)

I am not sure what's wrong with the logic I'm using for join.

**P.S - My aim is to find all the tables which are greater than 100GB in Size and have indexType as 'P'**

EDIT - Sharing relevant columns from `DBC.INDICES` table

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| DatabaseName | TableName  | IndexNumber | IndexType | UniqueFlag |   IndexName   | ColumnName | ColumnPosition |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| Some DB      | Some Table |           1 | P         | N          | IndexNamehere | ColumnA    |              1 |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: how does the indices table look like?

Comment: `SELECT Distinct ` will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your key is duplicated in `dbc.indices` table. For a single `TableName` ,`dbc.indices` table has more then one entry so when you join `dbc.tablesize` table records got duplicated so the `SUM` is applied on duplicate records so the mistake in calculation.

Try this way

```
SELECT a.TableName,
       a.DatabaseName,
       Sum(CurrentPerm / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )) AS Size_in_GB
FROM   dbc.tablesize a
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT b.TableName,
                             b.DatabaseName
             FROM   dbc.indices b
             --where b.indexType='P'
             ) b
         ON a.TableName = b.TableName
            AND a.DatabaseName = b.DatabaseName

GROUP  BY a.TableName,
          a.DatabaseName
ORDER  BY Size_in_GB DESC
```

Comment: Your answer did the trick ! Can you elaborate what does 'duplicated key' mean exactly and how does it affect?

Comment: @PirateX - updated check now.. am bit poor in English if you still didn't understood.. tell me will add a demo

Answer (score 2):

What is confusing?

You clearly have tables that have multiple indexes.  Each index is going to result in the table appearing more than one time for the aggregation.

For what you want:

> My aim is to find all the tables which are greater than 100GB in Size
>   and have indexType as 'P'

I would suggest moving the index comparison to the `where` clause:

```
select t.TableName, t.DatabaseName,
       sum(tCurrentPerm/(1024*1024*1024)) as Size_in_GB
from dbc.tablesize t
where exists (select 1
              from dbc.indices i
              where t.TableName = i.TableName and t.DatabaseName = i.DatabaseName and
                    i.indexType = 'P'
             )
group by 1,2
order by Size_in_GB desc
```

You can add `having Size_in_GB > 100` before the `order by` if you want to add that filter as well.

Comment: I really like your answer, can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

`dbc.IndidesV` (never use the old deprecated non-V-views) has one row per column per index.

You can simply add a condition to restrict it to a single row: `where IndexType = 'P' and ColumnPosition = 1`

And it's more efficient to do an early aggregation, i.e. aggregate before the join:

```
select t.*
from 
 (
   select TableName, DatabaseName,
      sum(CurrentPerm/(1024*1024*1024)) as Size_in_GB
   from dbc.TableSizeV
   group by 1,2
   having Size_in_GB > 100
 ) as dt
join dbc.IndicesV b 
  on a.TableName = b.TableName
 and a.DatabaseName=b.DatabaseName
where IndexType = 'P' 
  and ColumnPosition = 1
order by Size_in_GB desc;
```

But why do you want to filter for that `IndexType=P`, don't you care about other objects > 100GB (NoPI/Columnar tables, Join Indices)? Btw, this doesn't return all tables with a PI, only `IndexNumber=1` does.

Depending on your needs you might better join to `dbc.TablesV` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S - My aim is to find all the tables which are greater than 100GB
>   in Size and have indexType as 'P'

If you only want to find certain tables for which an index exists, you shouln't join at all. Use `EXISTS` instead. This puts your condition in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause where it belongs and you don't have issues with your condition duplicating your records (in your case: it doesn't matter anymore when a table has more than one matching index).

```
select tablename, databasename, sum(currentperm/(1024*1024*1024)) as size_in_gb 
from dbc.tablesize ts
group by tablename, databasename
having sum(currentperm/(1024*1024*1024)) > 100
and exists
(
  select *
  from dbc.indices i
  where i.tablename = ts.tablename and i.databasename = ts.databasename
  and i.indexType = 'P'
)
order by Size_in_GB desc;
```